# I have a static website, and all the data is already available. Should I use getStaticProps method to pass the data as prop?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js for creating a static website. The data is already available, and I'm importing the data directly to the component route inside the Pages folder. Is there any difference if I change it to getStaticPorps() and pass the data as a prop?

```
import servicesData from "../data/servicesData.json";

export default function services() {
  return (
    <>
        {servicesData.map(({ service }) => (
          <div key={service}>
             {service}
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the next.js documentation

When exporting a function called getServerSideProps (Server-Side Rendering) from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps. This is useful if you want to fetch data that changes often, and have the page update to show the most current data.

In this case, since you're importing, I suppose, static data, its better to use getStaticProps instead of getServerSideProps

if you want to read more, [check out the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props)

Good luck on your projects and have a nice day

Comment: Question isn't about using `getServerSideProps`, it's about whether to use `getStaticProps` or not use any data fetching method at all.